# How does createElementNS work?

Tags: javascript, svg

I don't really understand how does createElementNS works. For example:

```
svg = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
group = document.createElementNS(svg,"g");
```

Does this connect to the specified namespace and gets the definitions for the g element?

If so... if placed inside a for there will be some kind of request to the specified url?

Is there another way to create a g element? One that does not require online connection?

I don't think so because I don't see any requests going there but still... is a bit ambiguous.

The reason why I'm asking is that something is greatly slowing my script down and I don't know exactly what.

Comment: I don't think an html page retrieves any data from the namespace address. 

When defining a namespace in other languages (C++, Java), it is essentially a string label. I think that people use the address because it refers to the exact specification of the namespace they are using. For instance, if you had a namespace called "svg", that gives someone looking at the code no additional info. If you input the address into your web browser, you get every detail of the namespace capabilities. Afaik, it's just a great way to organize namespaces. It also separates different versions of the standard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does this connect to the specified namespace and gets the definitions for the g element?

No. You can't "connect" to a namespace. `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` is a unique identifier for the namespace, but namespaces are not URLs. The software handing the DOM needs to understand SVG (and will have the namespace mapped internally to its understanding of it).

The URL `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` is a document that tells readers where to find more information about SVG, but that is just the authors being helpful, there is no programatic significance of a document existing there.

Comment: Then why it must be that string and not "randomString" Anyway... ty for answer (I'll accept it in 9 minutes). The form was deceiving.

Comment: @zozo — Because software that knows SVG knows that the SVG namespace is `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` and doesn't know what namespace `randomString` is. The authors of the SVG specification *could* have picked `randomString` to represent the namespace, but they didn't.